# FB Like button only showing on FB site if comment is left

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am working on this site for a client: http://djzimmie.com/2012/03/08/miss-march-2011/

The linter says everything is okay, but when I go to like the page, I click like, and don't leave a comment, it doesn't show that I've liked it on my Facebook page. If I type in a comment, and then post, it shows up fine. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Okay here is some info:

Here is my namespace code:

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Here is a link to the linter that shows that everything is okay: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdjzimmie.com%2F2012%2F03%2F08%2Fmiss-march-2011%2F

Here is the code I am using right inside my body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=158780564242930";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then last but not least the button code:

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

As mentioned, I cant get the like button to show without leaving a comment.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmm no its definitely not spam.  As stated above the fb like button isnt functioning properly.  I cant get a simple like to show on the page, only a like with a comment left will display.

Comment: I can copy/paste my code here but I figured a link to the page would be easier as you could see it all.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @ObscureRobot Sorry, I was confused what you were asking.  I thought u were referring to the content of the page being spam :/  Sorry once again.  I added the details to the post.  Hopefully that sheds more light.

Comment: much better - I'm deleting my previous comments.

Comment: Right on thanks.  Im wondering if this anything to do with the namespace perhaps.  Ive tried the HTML5, and the FBML versions the plugin creator gives me, and it does the same thing.  I am totally stumped on this.

Comment: Followup to this was that FB was acting up....I went back to this a couple days later and it was working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followup to this was that FB was acting up....I went back to this a couple days later and it was working as expected